# Displays a few lines on same graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I've asked a similar question before, but this time I have a slightly more complicated issue.
I have a list of lists, and I want to show a few of the lines in the list.

The following code will plot code 36 lines:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[allbeeposition[[1 ;; 36]]]]
```

Instead, how could I show only a few lines, then skip a few more, and then show another group of lines?
For example: plot the first 3 lines, then skip 3, then plot the next 3, then skip 3 etc (on the same graph).

Comment: A possible hint at a solution: `alist = Range[30];` `blist = Flatten[#, 1] &@Partition[alist, 3][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];` and `NumberLinePlot[{alist, blist}]`

Comment: To manipulate lists see the tutorial on [`Lists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Lists.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Syed, use Flatten and Partition solved the problem.

For my case I used the code:

```
blist= Flatten[alist[[fromHere ;; upToHere]]];                            
blist= Partition[blist,numbersIwant,numbersIwant+numberToSkip];            
blist= Flatten[blist];                                                     
blist= Partition[blist,returnPartitionSizeOFalist]
```

and with numbers for example:

```
blist= Flatten[alist[[1 ;; 36]]];                            
blist= Partition[blist,3*8,6*8];            
blist= Flatten[blist];                                                     
blist= Partition[blist,8]
```